# Does for any non-negative discrete random variable $X$ hold $P(X \neq 0) \geq \frac{(E[X])^2}{E[X^2]}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

> Suppose $X$ is a non-negative random variable on $\mathbb{Z}$ with finite second moment. Is it always true that $P(X \neq 0) \geq \frac{(E[X])^2}{E[X^2]}$?

I managed to prove only a weaker bound:

$$P(X \neq 0) = 1 - P(X = 0) \geq 1 - P(X \leq 0) = 1 - P(-X \geq 0) = 1 - P(EX -X \geq EX) = 1 - P(|EX -X| \geq EX) \geq 1 - \frac{Var[X]}{(E[X])^2} = 2 - \frac{E[X^2]}{(E[X])^2}$$

by Chebyshev inequality.

Unfortunately, this bound is always weaker than what I need due to that fact that $\inf\{t + t^{-1}| t \in \mathbb{R}_+\} = 2$.

But that stronger inequality holds for several large families of distributions:

For binomial $X$ with parameters $n$ and $p$ we have: $P(X \neq 0) = 1 - (1-p)^n \geq \frac{n p^2}{p(1-p) + np^2} = \frac{(E[X])^2}{E[X^2]}$

For negative binomial $X$ with parameters $r$ and $p$ we have: $P(X \neq 0) = 1 - (1-p)^r \geq \frac{pr}{pr+1} = \frac{(E[X])^2}{E[X^2]}$

For Poisson $X$ with parameter $\lambda$ we have: $P(X \neq 0) = 1 - e^{-\lambda} \geq \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1} = \frac{(E[X])^2}{E[X^2]}$

However, I do not know how to prove it in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By C-S:

$$ E[X] = E [ X {\bf 1}_{X>0} ] \le (E [X^2])^{1/2} P(X>0)^{1/2}.$$

Therefore, assuming $E[X^2]>0$ (equivalent, under the assumption to $P(X \neq 0) > 0$),

$$ P(X>0) \ge \frac{E[X]^2}{E[X^2]}.$$